# Key combination AltGr+Alt+h is not detected in xev

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

I recently added the following customization to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` as an include file:

```
partial alphanumeric_keys xkb_symbols "vim" {
        key <AC06>      { [         h,          H,      Left,      Left ]       };
        key <AC07>      { [         j,          J,    Down,    Down ] };
        key <AC08>      { [         k,          K,          Up,    Up ] };
        key <AC09>      { [         l,          L,      Right,      Right ]     };
};
```

As far as I can see, most key combinations are working as expected (`AltGr + Ctrl + h` moves the cursor one word to the left, `AltGr + Shit + h` selects characters to the left, etc). However, I found that xev doesn't detect `AltGr + Alt + h` at all. On the contrary, pressing `AltGr + Alt + j` shows:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1e00001,
    root 0x6aa, subw 0x0, time 2737246, (1313,804), root:(1314,829),
    state 0x88, keycode 44 (keysym 0xff54, Down), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 88
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I don't know if that's the output that should be expected, but as I said, most applications seem to receive the desired key presses (e.g. Firefox receives Alt+Right arrow when I press `AltGr + Alt + l`). Having said that, if I made a mistake in my initial configuration, please let me know.

Why this particular key combination (`AltGr + Alt h`) is not being detected?

Comment: Maybe your window manager catches that key combination or a subset thereof (like AltGr-h or Alt-h… or possibly even Ctrl-Alt-h where Ctrl-Alt‑ is often treated the same as AltGr‑)?

Comment: Interesting idea, but MODKEY is set to Mod4Mask instead of Alt, and there are no additional keybindings for the letter h. Even if that were the case, `xev` should show something for that particular key, right?

Comment: You could run `evtest` and verify that all 3 keys are being detected. If evtest doesn't report it, your problem is beneath the X layer.

Comment: @TAAPSogeking Sorry, I initially misunderstood the output. In fact, evtest doesn't report it. `evtest` only shows `type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 00`. There are a few letters that are not detected: `Altgr+Alt+{g,h,b,n}`. Any idea what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: I've experienced that some keyboards won't recognize it if certain combination of keys are pressed. Could probably confirm this by testing with an additional keyboard. But that wouldn't really solve the issue... a workaround could be remapping keys such that you are physically pressing different keys to achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I will try to test this with another keyboard. It is still a bit unusual that precisely those key combinations are not working. Do you report that kind of thing as a driver issue?